# Test Commands are not recognised in Django

Tags: django, docker

I'm running Django Tests in a Docker container and using manage.py to run my tests. My test files import `TestCase` from `django.test`, but for some reason commands like `AssertEqual` are not recognised:

```
AttributeError: 'TestSession' object has no attribute 'AssertEqual'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command is [`assertEqual`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertEqual) (note the lowercase 'a' in assert), not `AssertEqual`.

Comment: you're right, I got confused between the python and django syntax

Comment: Glad it solved your problem, but I'm not sure what you mean - the Django syntax is the same as Python ;)